# creating numpy matrix from nested arrays in a list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list as follows.

```
list=[[np.array([[-3.,  3.,  3.],
         [-3.,  3.,  3.],
         [-3.,  3.,  3.],
         [ 1.,  4.,  2.],
         [-0.,  4., -5.],
         [ 3.,  6., -5.]])],
 [np.array([[-1.,  2., -3.],
         [-1.,  2., -3.],
         [-1.,  2., -3.],  
         [-2.,  2.,  1.],
         [-0.,  4., -0.],
         ])]]
```

The list contains numpy array. It should be noted that the number of rows in each numpy array is different but the number of columns are same. As in the example, the number if rows in first array is 6 where as in second array it is 5.
My goal is to create a numpy matrix or array from the above list such as.

```
         [-3.,  3.,  3.]
         [-3.,  3.,  3.]
         [-3.,  3.,  3.]
         [ 1.,  4.,  2.]
         [-0.,  4., -5.]
         [ 3.,  6., -5.] 
         [-1.,  2., -3.]                         

         [-1.,  2., -3.]
         [-1.,  2., -3.]
         [-2.,  2.,  1.]
         [-0.,  4., -0.]
```

Is there any fast an efficient way to do so in python? I have 1000s of these array which I need to convert.

Comment: `np.vstack(tuple_of_arrays)` should do the job

Comment: These nested arrays can be only accessed using the list index as they are inside the list and not stand alone arrays outside. Moreover, in actual, I have a lost list which is comprised of 10000 arrays and not just 2 as shown in this example.

Comment: Pass them in as `list[:,0]` or `tuple(list[:,0])` if that doesn't work.

Comment: This requires the concatenation axis must be matched and in my case it is not matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `np.ravel` the list before `np.vstack`:

as in your sample:

```
l =[[np.array([[-3.,  3.,  3.],
         [-3.,  3.,  3.],
         [-3.,  3.,  3.],
         [ 1.,  4.,  2.],
         [-0.,  4., -5.],
         [ 3.,  6., -5.]])],
 [np.array([[-1.,  2., -3.],
         [-1.,  2., -3.],
         [-1.,  2., -3.],  
         [-2.,  2.,  1.],
         [-0.,  4., -0.],
         ])]]

np.vstack(np.ravel(l))

Out[119]:
array([[-3.,  3.,  3.],
       [-3.,  3.,  3.],
       [-3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  4.,  2.],
       [-0.,  4., -5.],
       [ 3.,  6., -5.],
       [-1.,  2., -3.],
       [-1.,  2., -3.],
       [-1.,  2., -3.],
       [-2.,  2.,  1.],
       [-0.,  4., -0.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` or `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to "unpack" the arrays and then concatenate:

```
>>> np.concatenate(next(zip(*l)),axis=0)
```

or

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> np.concatenate([*chain.from_iterable(l)],axis=0)
```

output in either case

```
array([[-3.,  3.,  3.],
       [-3.,  3.,  3.],
       [-3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  4.,  2.],
       [-0.,  4., -5.],
       [ 3.,  6., -5.],
       [-1.,  2., -3.],
       [-1.,  2., -3.],
       [-1.,  2., -3.],
       [-2.,  2.,  1.],
       [-0.,  4., -0.]])
```

Both are fast:

```
>>> timeit(lambda:np.concatenate(next(zip(*l)),axis=0))
1.8132231349591166
>>> timeit(lambda:np.concatenate([*chain.from_iterable(l)],axis=0))
1.730023997137323
>>> timeit(lambda:np.vstack(np.ravel(l)))
7.647858377080411
```